# How to execute code continuously in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a HTML-file and a PHP-file. The index.php displays a value which gets transferred to the servo.php. The servo.php writes the value in a file called /dev/servoblaster.

Currently the value only gets displayed if i click the button with my function. 
**I would like that the value is displayed and sent *continuously* and not by the press of a button.**

The two files can you find here:
[servo.php](http://pastebin.com/Hs3PzK2i)
[index.html](http://pastebin.com/rmZRABer)

The function: (You will find it also in the HTML-file)

```
    function tilt() { var tilt = document.getElementById("tiltRange").value;
                      document.getElementById("tilt_Range").innerHTML = tilt;
                      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      xhttp.open("GET", "servo.php?dir=P1-11=" + tilt, true);
                      xhttp.send();
                    }
```

The body tag of the HTML-file:

```
    <button onclick="tilt()">Tilt</button>

    <input type="range" id="tiltRange" value="140" max="170" min="60">

    <text id="tilt_Range"></text>
```

Comment: Use setInterval function. setInterval('tilt',5000);

Comment: do you want to set a timer and call the function every x seconds?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald If the function gets executed properly then yes.

Comment: I'd rather use websockets instead timeouts in cases like this one. Take a look at this example: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Comment: Why don't you just bind change event of input element instead (eventually trigering it on document ready)??? Because if input value doesn't change, there is no reason to send useless request to server

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `setInterval` to call your script every `n` seconds:

```
setInterval(tilt, 5000);
```

Will call `tilt()` every 5 seconds...

EDIT:

Added `clearInterval` example:

```
var doIt = setInterval(tilt, 5000);
```

You can then clear / stop it like so:

```
clearInterval(doIt)
```

So you should assign a click handler to your "stop" button, that calls the clearInterval.

Comment: The 5000 milliseconds there is an arbitrary number I added for the example (as should be obvious) - It is down to OP to determine this functionality.  Personally I would have a check to see if the request is complete, if not don't call the function again, or something along those lines, but as I say that's an exercise for the OP.

Comment: Ya, that was my point. Better than using an interval would be to use a timeout recursively called on ajax complete

Comment: Indeed - why don't you add an answer to that effect? Sounds like an ideal solution for OP.

Comment: Because imho it is just a XY problem, OP should just bind change event to the input element to send request to server

Comment: @Stuart how can i stop the setInterval(tilt, 5000); function? I tried to stop it: I added a if loop to the tilt() function ( if (tiltstop == false) {...} ) Then i made a reset button which sets the variable tiltstop to true. But it did'nt work. So how could i stop the setInterval()?

Comment: Assign the `setInterval` to a variable, you can then use `clearInterval` to stop it. Ill add some code to my answer for you now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use setInterval to execute any code at certain time interval.

```
 setInterval(function () {
           document.getElementById("tiltRange").value;
                          document.getElementById("tilt_Range").innerHTML = tilt;
                          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                          xhttp.open("GET", "servo.php?dir=P1-11=" + tilt, true);
                          xhttp.send();

        },30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by "Dhara Parmar" on this page worked for me.

I needed a scroll event trigger, such as when a user scroll downs to a web page of a certain position, an event would occur, such as a pop out or an alert message.

Here is an example:

```
setInterval(function () 
    {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1200) // at what scroll position 
            {
                alert("hello");
            }

    }, 10); // time repetition interval in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You could you use setInterval in this case, using the following syntax:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () 
{
    var tilt = document.getElementById("tiltRange").value;
               document.getElementById("tilt_Range").innerHTML = tilt;
               var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
               xhttp.open("GET", "servo.php?dir=P1-11=" + tilt, true);
               xhttp.send();
}, 5000);
```

And when you want to stop it from doing that action, simply do:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Hope that helped :)
Let me know if that's not the case